# How to find the next ListView item that is not selected?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-2009

I want to search the ListView for the next unselected item, but only with windows APIs.

I tried with the `ListView_FindItem` macro but it's not working. The result is always -1:

```
function TNewListView.NextUnselected(I: Integer): Integer;
var FindInfo: TLVFindInfo;
    ItemInfo: TLVItem;
begin
 if not HandleAllocated then Exit(-1)
 else begin
   FillChar(ItemInfo, SizeOf(ItemInfo), 0);
   ItemInfo.mask:= LVIF_STATE;
   ItemInfo.state:= 0;
   ItemInfo.stateMask:= LVIS_SELECTED;

   FillChar(FindInfo, SizeOf(FindInfo), 0);
   FindInfo.flags:= LVFI_PARAM;
   FindInfo.lParam:= LPARAM(@ItemInfo);
   Result:= ListView_FindItem(Handle, I, FindInfo);
 end;
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to not work. At least on Windows 7. I cannot see any problem in your code (I even tried to specify `iItem` member of the `TLVItem` which is not necessary, just to try, but no luck). Out of topic, I know that you've spent a lot of time with this control, yet I would suggest VirtualTreeView.

Comment: It does not work because 1) you are using `ListView_FindItem()` incorrectly to begin with, and 2) it does not support the kind of search you are trying to perform. See my answer for alternatives that work.

Comment: I don't see any wrong usage of this macro. So I disagree with @Remy here in his point 1. The OP passes an item (`TLVItem`) structure to the `ListView_FindItem` marco in a hope to search by the state (mask). That this API function is not capable to search by the passed item only by their state is not a Delphi issue.

Comment: @Victoria your EXPECTATION of how the API *SHOULD* work is irrelevant.  IT DOES NOT WORK THE WAY THE OP IS USING IT.  [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_finditem). What I have described is the real *documented and tested* behavior for it. Please stop trying to confuse the OP with misinformation. The OP wants to know WHY his code doesn't work as coded. What I have described is the WHY, and the FIX. What you have described is merely a WISH in how you WANT the API to work instead.

Comment: @Remy, have I said something wrong? My initial comment is like _"this seems to not work"_ by which I was meant to say that the `ListView_FindItem` macro is not capable of searching items by state. That may lead to confusion, but not misinformation. In the end having a VirtualTreeView in your application is not so bad, so I don't think and I hope I didn't write anything bad.

Comment: @Remy, besides, my expectation, so as how OP used this macro relevant **is** (I still see no problem about using it this way expecting correct result). That it doesn't work that way is problem of MS, not EMBT.

Comment: @Victoria It's not a problem with the MS code at all. That behaves as designed. The fact that your expectation is that it behaves differently does not make it a defect.

Comment: @Marus Probable disappears if you run the list in virtual mode. Simples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `ListView_FindItem()` using the [`LVFI_PARAM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Commctrl/ns-commctrl-taglvfindinfow) flag:

> LVFI_PARAM
>
> Searches for a match between this structure's `lParam` member and the `lParam` member of an item's `LVITEM` structure.

That tells the ListView to compare the specified `TLVFindInfo.lParam` value **as-is** to the `lParam` of each list item until it finds a match.

If you are using the `TListView` in **non-virtual** mode (`OwnerData=False`), a list item's `lParam` value holds its corresponding `TListItem` object pointer.

If you are using the `TListView` in **virtual** mode (`OwnerData=True`), a list item's `lParam` value is always 0.

`ListView_FindItem()` (and the underlying `LVM_FINDITEM` message) can search for a list item by either its `Caption` (full or partial), its `lParam` <sup>1</sup>, or its position, but *nothing else*.

<sup>1: For example, the `TListItems.IndexOf()` method uses `ListView_FindItem()` to return the index of a specified `TListItem` object using an `lParam` search (which only works in non-virtual mode, where the `lParam` of each item is a `TListItem` object pointer).</sup>

You are trying to perform an `lParam` search as well, but you are using the *WRONG* `lParam` value to search for!  You are setting the `TLVFindInfo.lParam` value to **a pointer to a local `TLVItem` variable**, so the `LVFI_PARAM` comparisons will **never** find a matching list item.  That is why you are always getting a result of -1.

`ListView_FindItem()` is *essentially* doing the following logic in your example:

```
function ListView_FindItem(hWnd: HWND; iStart: Integer; const plvfi: TLVFindInfo): Integer;
var
  lvi: TLVItem;
begin
  for Result := iStart+1 to ListView_GetItemCount(hWnd)-1 do
  begin
    FillChar(lvi, SizeOf(lvi), 0);
    lvi.iIndex := Result;
    lvi.mask = LVIF_PARAM;
    ListView_GetItem(hWnd, lvi);
    if lvi.lParam = plvfi.lParam then // <-- NEVER FINDS A MATCH!
      Exit;
  end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

As you can see, the *contents* of your local `TLVItem` variable are NEVER USED at all, so it doesn't matter what you set the `TLVItem` fields to.

You are *expecting* `ListView_FindItem()` to *essentially* do the following logic instead, WHICH IS NOT HOW IT WORKS, AND IS NOT DOCUMENTED TO WORK THIS WAY:

```
function ListView_FindItem(hWnd: HWND; iStart: Integer; const plvfi: TLVFindInfo): Integer;
var
  lvi: TLVItem;
begin
  for Result := iStart+1 to ListView_GetItemCount(hWnd)-1 do
  begin
    FillChar(lvi, SizeOf(lvi), 0);
    lvi.iIndex := Result;
    lvi.mask = LVIF_STATE;
    lvi.stateMask := PLVItem(plvfi.lParam)^.stateMask;
    ListView_GetItem(hWnd, lvi);
    if lvi.state = PLVItem(plvfi.lParam)^.state then // <-- BUZZ, WRONG!
      Exit;
  end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

So, you simply cannot search for an item by state using `ListView_FindItem()`/`LVM_FINDITEM`, they do not support that kind of search.

You might be tempted to use `ListView_GetNextItem()`/`LVM_GETNEXTITEM`  instead:

> Searches for a list-view item that has the specified properties and bears the specified relationship to a specified item.

But, they can only be used to search for a list item that has specified characteristics enabled (such as having `LVNI_SELECTED` enabled).  They cannot be used to find an item that has an *ABSENCE* of specified characteristics (such as having `LVNI_SELECTED` disabled).

So, to do what you want, you will just have to manually iterate through the list items, using `ListView_GetItem()` or `ListView_GetItemState()` to retrieve each item's current state, until you find what you are looking for.

For example:

```
function TNewListView.NextUnselected(StartIndex: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if HandleAllocated then
  begin
    for Result := StartIndex+1 to ListView_GetItemCount(Handle)-1 do
    begin
      if (ListView_GetItemState(Handle, Result, LVIS_SELECTED) and LVIS_SELECTED) = 0 then
        Exit;
    end;

    // if you want to implement wrap-around searching, uncomment this...
    {
    for Result := 0 to StartIndex-1 do
    begin
      if (ListView_GetItemState(Handle, Result, LVIS_SELECTED) and LVIS_SELECTED) = 0 then
        Exit;
    end;
    }
  end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Or:

```
function TNewListView.NextUnselected(StartIndex: Integer): Integer;

  function IsNotSelected(Index: Integer): Boolean;
  var
    ItemInfo: TLVItem;
  begin
    FillChar(ItemInfo, SizeOf(ItemInfo), 0);
    ItemInfo.iItem := Index;
    ItemInfo.mask := LVIF_STATE;
    ItemInfo.stateMask := LVIS_SELECTED;
    ListView_GetItem(Handle, ItemInfo);
    Result := (ItemInfo.state and LVIS_SELECTED) = 0;
  end;

begin
  if HandleAllocated then
  begin
    for Result := StartIndex+1 to ListView_GetItemCount(Handle)-1 do
    begin
      if IsNotSelected(Result) then
        Exit;
    end;

    // if you want to implement wrap-around searching, uncomment this...
    {
    for Result := 0 to StartIndex-1 do
    begin
      if IsNotSelected(Result) then
        Exit;
    end;
    }
  end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Both approaches work for what you are attempting.

Comment: I've tried even non virtual mode, and asking for state ended up the same. I never received anything else than -1 from `ListView_FindItem` macro even using non virtual mode when finding an item (on Windows 7).

Comment: I would rephrase _"ListView_FindItem - They can only search for list items by either caption, lparam, or position, nothing else."_ as `lparam` is just what the OP use.

Comment: @Victoria `ListView_FindItem()` **cannot** be used in this situation. The OP is searching using the WRONG lparam value, which is why the search fails

Comment: Remy, the code in the question is correct. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Victoria yes, you are missing something - "*Since you are setting the `TLVFindInfo.lParam` value to **a pointer to a local TLVItem variable**, that comparison will **never find a match**...*" - [read the `LVFINDINFO` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taglvfindinfow): "*LVFI_PARAM - Searches for a match between this structure's `lParam` member and the `lParam` member of an item's `LVITEM` structure.*" Each list item's `lParam` will NEVER be the same value as the `lParam` that the OP is searching for.

Comment: I see nothing wrong on it. The OP is passing a `TLVItem` structure filled for a state search to that macro. It seems just that this control is not capable of this. I still don't understand. Sorry :)

Comment: @Victoria you are still missing the point. You **cannot** search for a **local `TLVItem` variable** as the `TLVFindInfo.lParam` for `ListView_FindItem()`.  When using the `LVFI_LPARAM` flag, `ListView_FindItem()` searches for the `TLVFindInfo.lParam` value **as-is**. None of the list items will have an `lParam` that matches **the address of a local variable**.  `ListView_FindItem()` DOES NOT dereference the `TLVFindInfo.lParam` to access the caller's `TLVItem` and then search for the `TLVItem.lParam` value, like you and OP clearly think it does.

Comment: Still don't understand. That macro (and its underlying message) is synchronous, hence there is no need to worry if the passed structure is **local**. What I wanted to say is that you mention _"They can only search for list items by either caption, **lparam**.."_ which is truth, but not in case when you want to search for item state. That's all :) The code in the question is correct in my view; just this Windows control behaves wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179217/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-victoria).